# How to draw the paths of a networkX graph using different colours

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I created a graph using python networkX as shown in the following code.
The graph has three paths and i want to draw each path using different color.
For example, I want to draw path 1 ( i.e.[2, 1, 4, 3, 11])  using red color,  path 2 ( i.e. [1, 0, 3, 11, 10] using blue color and path 3 ( i.e. [10, 11, 3, 4, 1]) using yellow color.
Pls how do I modify the d code to draw the graph with specified colors? This is my first program using python and networkX package.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

G=nx.Graph(name="buba")
routes = [[2, 1, 4, 3, 11], [1, 0, 3, 11, 10], [10, 11, 3, 4, 1]]
edges = [ (2,1), (1,4), (4,3), (3,11), (1,0), (0,3), (11,10)]
for r in routes:
     G.add_nodes_from(r)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

print("Graph has %d nodes with %d edges" %(G.number_of_nodes(),    
G.number_of_edges()))
nx.draw_networkx(G,with_labels=True)
plt.savefig('this.png')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 8):

This code produces the figure below.  Since your paths overlapped, I plotted them with different thicknesses so that you can see them all.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

G=nx.Graph(name="buba")
routes = [[2, 1, 4, 3, 11], [1, 0, 3, 11, 10], [10, 11, 3, 4, 1]]
edges = []
for r in routes:
    route_edges = [(r[n],r[n+1]) for n in range(len(r)-1)]
    G.add_nodes_from(r)
    G.add_edges_from(route_edges)
    edges.append(route_edges)

print("Graph has %d nodes with %d edges" %(G.number_of_nodes(),    
G.number_of_edges()))

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos=pos)
colors = ['r', 'b', 'y']
linewidths = [20,10,5]
for ctr, edgelist in enumerate(edges):
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos=pos,edgelist=edgelist,edge_color = colors[ctr], width=linewidths[ctr])
plt.savefig('this.png')
```

[image]

---

So what have I changed from your code?

1) The main thing is I created lists of all the edges for each path (the route_edges).

2) I also defined a set of positions `pos` for the nodes in `G`, because I was going to need to plot things several times and I needed to be sure they were in the same place each time I plotted.

3) To plot a subset of the edges I used `nx.draw_networkx_edges` and sent it a list of edges to plot.  I specified the color at this point (as well as the thickness).

Comment: Joel Thank you. That is exactly what i want

Comment: Sorry Joe. The node label did not appear in the figure. A node label is either 1 or 2 or 3 and so on

Comment: fixed it.  The arguments used if you just do `nx.draw_networkx` are a bit different from if you use the `nx.draw_networkx_nodes`, so I had misremembered.